# How to perform multiple windows command in cmd using python in same shell

Tags: python-3.x, shell, subprocess, command-line-arguments

I want to perform some couple of command one after one and store into variable in same shell. Whenever I try to perform next command it executes in new shell

```
import subprocess

cmd1 = 'cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\openvpn\\bin\\'
output = subprocess.getoutput(cmd1) # it goes to the above directory

cmd2 = 'openvpn.exe --help'
output2 = subprocess.getoutput(cmd2)
```

At the cmd2 when it runs,a new shell perform this command and tells--
'openvpn.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I want to perform couple of commands one after another and store into variables. So I can use that variables in other commands.

Comment: The easy approach is to put all the commands into one file (`tmp.cmd`) and then run that file.

Comment: I want to perform couple of more commands one after another so i can store into variables and I have to use some variables in other commands.

Comment: Again, put all those commands into `tmp.cmd`, then run `tmp.cmd` from Python. The alternative is to do `os.chdir()` in Python instead. The horrible version of this is to use the `Pexpect` module and simulate input to a shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `run` method, like so:

```
output = subprocess.run(['openvpn.exe', '--help'], cwd='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\openvpn\\bin\\', capture_output=True)
```

> - cwd = current working directory (where should the command run)
> - capture_output = record the stdout, stderr streams

Then you can access your results within the stdout, stderr properties:

```
output.stdout  # will give you back the output of the command.
```

You weren't getting any results because the `cd` command has no effect within `subprocess`. It has to do with the way `cd` works in the first place - no process can change another processes working directory.